# Nam console wont open in ns2

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I have tried running a tcl file but the nam console isnt opening. I am completely new to networks and I only have kali linux on my system but the same happened when I tried from ubuntu too. I have installed ns2, nam and xgraph. I have tried running the last code in the website:

[installation guide](https://www.absingh.com/ns2/)

The tcl file runs alright. But the nam console wont open and its stuck like this

[image]

Comment: Please avoid posting screenshots of text and instead post the text in code tags ( the `{}` button)

Comment: NAM is a graphical / GUI package. ... Doesn't work with CLI. .... Get nam : `# apt install nam` ......... NAM console image, valid nam packages https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNLXVVSnNFSXpWUGs?resourcekey=0-l7ZPIxkG17JwSO5CDA4ONA&usp=sharing ........ P.S.: If you have an old version of Debian / Kali → then the nam .deb package is corrupt.